# Lodash - filter by string 1,2

Tags: filter, lodash

I have string

```
"1,2" // which is from the db.field
```

I am trying to filter with lodash and some thing like the following worked

```
_.filter(jsonArray, function(res) { return (res.id == 1 || res.id == 2); });
```

Please assume jsonArray  as follows:

```
[
{ 'id': '1', 'age': 60 },
{ 'id': '2', 'age': 70 },
{ 'id': '3', 'age': 22 },
{ 'id': '4', 'age': 33 }
];
```

here the problem is I need to split the sting 1,2 and apply,

But note that 1,2 is not always 1,2 - it could be 1,2,3 and this string is dynamic from db.field.

Now I am searching if there is any way I can just use the string say like

```
-.filter(jsonArray, function(res){ return res.id <is equal to one of the value in 1,2,3,4 >})
```

I think its obvious the split this string into array and ... but I am not sure of doing it, help it out please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to split `db.field` to make it as array of `ids` that can be evaluated easily when matching items. Next, use the [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) that you've already constructed to check if such items match the `ids` using [includes](https://lodash.com/docs#includes).

```
var ids = db.field.split(',').map(Number);
var result = _.filter(jsonArray, function(res) {
  return _.includes(ids, res.id);
});
```

```js
var db = { field: '1,2' };


var jsonArray = [
  { 'id': 1, 'age': 60 },
  { 'id': 2, 'age': 70 },
  { 'id': 3, 'age': 22 },
  { 'id': 4, 'age': 33 }
];

var ids = db.field.split(',').map(Number);
var result = _.filter(jsonArray, function(res) {
  return _.includes(ids, res.id);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.12.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried your code directly and it worked but when I implemented to my code zone it did not work. I was puzzled initially and found out this.
When the array is 
`var jsonArray = [`
  `{ 'id': 1, 'age': 60 },`
 `{ 'id': 2, 'age': 70 },`
  `{ 'id': 3, 'age': 22 },`
 `{ 'id': 4, 'age': 33 }`
`];`

Hope you see the difference, here the id field is integer and not string.
It just gave me a empty array.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please check the update, I basically added `.map(Number)` in the `db.field` split array to convert the array of strings to an array of numbers.